# Erroneous use of auto type specifier with Eigen objects

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, eigen, auto

I have a main function which looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::Vector3d;
using namespace std;

void ext_func(vector<Vector3d> &a, vector<Vector3d> &b, vector<Vector3d> &c);
int main()
{
    vector<Vector3d> a = {};
    a.push_back(Vector3d(1.,1.,0.));
    a.push_back(Vector3d(2.,1.,0.));

    vector<Vector3d> b = {};
    b.push_back(Vector3d(.5,.7,2.));
    b.push_back(Vector3d(0.,.2,-1.2));

    vector<Vector3d> c = {};
    c.push_back(Vector3d::Zero());
    c.push_back(Vector3d::Zero());

    ext_func(a,b,c);

}
```

From `main`, I call an external function:

```
void ext_func(vector<Vector3d> &a, vector<Vector3d> &b, vector<Vector3d> &c)
{
    double fac = 0.01;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        auto a_temp = a[i] + fac * b[i] / 50.;
        cout << "Before" << endl << fac*a_temp << endl;
        a[i] = a_temp;
        c[i] += fac*a_temp;
        cout << "After" << endl << fac*a_temp << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Before
 0.010001
0.0100014
    4e-06
After
 0.010002
0.0100028
    8e-06

Before
     0.02
0.0100004
 -2.4e-06
After
     0.02
0.0100008
 -4.8e-06
```

Which is not what I want to get (I want a_temp to stay constant once it's assigned). I understand that the problem is that I assign a new value to `&a` and so when I'm calling `a_temp` I'm basically incrementing a second time my initial `a[i]`. The problem is solved by replacing `auto` with `Vector3d` or `Vector3d&&`.

What I'm not sure about is what is `auto` really doing here.

Comment: Probably a template expression, (to compute `a[i] + fac * b[i] / 50.` without extra `Vector3d` temporary).

Comment: `template <typename> struct Debug; Debug<decltype(a_temp)> dummy;` should give you the type in error message.

Comment: fwiw, `const auto a_temp = ...` will deduce the type and add constness.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: but the `const` is probably as useless than for `r` in `int i = 40; const auto& r = i; assert(r == 40); i += 2; assert(r == 42 /* r has "changed"*/);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh right, it doesnt help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating with matrices in the eigen library, the overloaded operators return an object representing the calculation expression. This expression is not yet evaluated (ie. the actual calculation is not yet performed).

In your example, the type derived by `auto` is `Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient1_op<double>, const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>>>>`.

The actual evaluation of the expression is done when the result is needed (eg. when assigning to a variable, printing, etc.).

Since `a_temp` in your case is the expression (not the result), the expression is evaluated multiple times :

- when printing it as part of the `Before` line
- when assigning to `a[i]`
- when assigning to `c[i]`
- when printing it as part of the `After` line

The second of these ends up modifying one of the operands of the expression, so subsequent evaluations of the expression will have a different result.

Comment: Thanks! Now everything makes sense

Comment: For the record, this is documented [there](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html#title3).